# Print and update a matrix in-place

Tags: python, curses, urwid

I have a matrix represented as a list of lists (but can easily change this representation if it would help). I will be updating this matrix as the program runs. I would like to have the matrix displayed on the screen in some standard way. So something like

[image]

I would like this display to update as the program runs.

For example,

```
def updatematrix():
#Change some entries in the matrix

A = [[3,2,3],[1,2,1],[2,8,6]]
while(True):
    updatematrix()
    display(A) #This would ideally change the display in place.
```

What is a good way of doing this? (In fact I will be changing entire columns and rows and will eventually want to make the changed row/column be in a different color.)

I am happy to use any free libraries that might be useful.

Comment: what is your question? if its  "is this possible?" the answer is yes.  if its "what library to use?" the easiest is probably curses. if its "will you do my code for me?" the answer is probably not

Comment: @JoranBeasley You ask a very good question. It would be really great if someone answered "I recommend X for this and this is some code that will get you started displaying your example matrix."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggeest using the curses library, which is part of the standard python libraries
http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

I've included a bit of a hacked together example

```
import curses
import time

mywindow = curses.initscr()

matrix = [[3,2,3],[1,2,1],[2,8,6]]

def updateMatrix(m):
    m[1][1] = m[1][1] * 2
    return m

def getMarixString(m):
    x = ''
    for row in m:
        x += ' '.join(str(item) for item in row)
        x += "\n"
    return x

z = 10
while z > 1:
    matrix = updateMatrix(matrix)
    mywindow.addstr(0,0, getMarixString(matrix))
    mywindow.refresh()
    z -= 1
    time.sleep(3)

curses.endwin()
quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. I have been put off by all the low level details before.  Would you mind showing me how to start with it for my problem?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html   here is a nice tutorial on getting started :)

Comment: I've added a simple example / demo on using the curses lib to my answer

Answer (score -1):

Matrix calculations are possible, not sure about the colour part. You may want to look at Numpy arrays and operations depending on what you will do in your updatematrix(), http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Functions_by_Category

Comment: My question is just about displaying the matrix and updating it in-place.